# Como mudar posição de todos os elementos da matriz, trocando o número da linha pela coluna?

Tags: c#, .net, array, matriz

Eu tentei este algoritmo mas o resultado fica o mesmo apos esta troca

```
  int[,] array = new int[10,10];

  for (int l = 0; l <  10; l++)
    for (int c = 0; c < 10; c++)
     {               
       int temp = array[l, c];
       array[l, c] = array[c, l];
       array[c, l] = temp;
    }
```

Output antes da troca

> ```
>  0 | 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 | 5 | 6 | 7 | 8 | 9 |
>  0 | 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 | 5 | 6 | 7 | 8 | 9 |
>  0 | 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 | 5 | 6 | 7 | 8 | 9 |
>  0 | 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 | 5 | 6 | 7 | 8 | 9 |
>  0 | 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 | 5 | 6 | 7 | 8 | 9 |
>  0 | 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 | 5 | 6 | 7 | 8 | 9 |
>  0 | 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 | 5 | 6 | 7 | 8 | 9 |
>  0 | 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 | 5 | 6 | 7 | 8 | 9 |
>  0 | 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 | 5 | 6 | 7 | 8 | 9 |
>  0 | 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 | 5 | 6 | 7 | 8 | 9 |
>
> depois da troca
>
>  0 | 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 | 5 | 6 | 7 | 8 | 9 |
>  0 | 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 | 5 | 6 | 7 | 8 | 9 |
>  0 | 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 | 5 | 6 | 7 | 8 | 9 |
>  0 | 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 | 5 | 6 | 7 | 8 | 9 |
>  0 | 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 | 5 | 6 | 7 | 8 | 9 |
>  0 | 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 | 5 | 6 | 7 | 8 | 9 |
>  0 | 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 | 5 | 6 | 7 | 8 | 9 |
>  0 | 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 | 5 | 6 | 7 | 8 | 9 |
>  0 | 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 | 5 | 6 | 7 | 8 | 9 |
>  0 | 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 | 5 | 6 | 7 | 8 | 9 |
> ```

Comment: Se o código é só isso, todos valem o mesmo, então não tem como notar diferença. Se colocar um código real, um [mcve], fica mais fácil ajudar.

Comment: Mas não entendo bem porque não resulta

Comment: Gostei das duas soluções nao dá para marcar as duas? é que funcionam as duas xD

Comment: Só pode votar em todas, aceitar só uma, tem que escolher a que é a que mais aproxima do que deseja. Funcionar, funciona, uma gera um objeto novo. Eu fiz uma que economiza memória, é mais rápida e vai na linha do que você postou, eu achei uma solução melhor, por isso postei, mas a decisão é sua.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Se quiser fazer *inline* basta começar a verificação da coluna a partir da linha que parou. O problema é que se você começa do 0 ele inverte o que já foi invertido, então volta ao lugar original. Assim:

```
using static System.Console;

public class Program {
    public static void Main() {
        int[,] array = new int[10,10];
        for (int l = 0; l < 10; l++) {
            for (int c = 0; c < 10; c++) array[l, c] = c;
        }
        for (int l = 0; l < 10; l++) {
            for (int c = 0; c < 10; c++) Write($"{array[l, c]} ");
            WriteLine();
        }
        WriteLine();
        for (int l = 0; l < 10; l++) {
            for (int c = l; c < 10; c++) { // <========== mudei aqui, veja o l
                int temp = array[l, c];
                array[l, c] = array[c, l];
                array[c, l] = temp;
            }
        }
        for (int l = 0; l < 10; l++) {
            for (int c = 0; c < 10; c++) Write($"{array[l, c]} ");
            WriteLine();
        }
    }
}
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/J5vcpD). E [no **.NET Fiddle**](https://dotnetfiddle.net/IuN9nd). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/bigown/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/Array/InvertMatrix.cs).

Answer (score 2):

Seu algoritmo não parece fazer nenhum sentido pra mim.

Transpor uma matriz, irá inverter o tamanho dela (linhas viram colunas e colunas viram linhas).

O certo seria fazer algo como:

```
public int[,] Transpor(int[,] matriz)
{
    int w = matriz.GetLength(0);
    int h = matriz.GetLength(1);

    int[,] novaMatriz = new int[h, w];

    for (int i = 0; i < w; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < h; j++)
        {
            novaMatriz[j, i] = matriz[i, j];
        }
    }

    return novaMatriz;
}
```

[Veja funcionando no .NET Fiddle.](https://dotnetfiddle.net/zgv3Lz)